# How to remove ListView's add item animation?

Tags: listview, animation, windows-runtime

I have a `ListView` and I edited its `ItemContainerStyle` to modify some style but I don't know how to remove that annoying animation when you add an item.

With an `ItemsControl`, when you add a new item, it appears instantly, without any animation.

With `ListView`, the item takes a while and then, it starts an animation to show up.

I just want to remove that `add animation` and when I click on `Add item` it appears instantly, no extra stuff.

I think that it should belong to `ItemContainerStyle` but even I commented out all visualstate animations and is still there. I'm missing something out.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These animations are called transitions and they are part of `ListViewStyle`. To change it right click on `ListView` control in the designer and select `Edit Template` > `Edit a Copy...`. This will add the built-in style to your XAML.

The following part of the style is of interest to you:

```
<Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
    <Setter.Value>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
            <ContentThemeTransition/>
            <ReorderThemeTransition/>
            <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I'm not sure which animation exactly you dislike but try removing `AddDeleteThemeTransition` and/or `EntranceThemeTransition` from `TransitionCollection`. It should do the trick.

Don't forget to make sure the modified style is applied to the desired `ListView`.

Comment: This is what I love from this framework. I was a WPF developer but it seems that I have a lot more to learn. Thank you.

Comment: Dude, copying the whole style/template is too heavy-handed. Instead, add the following inside ListView element:

                    <ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
                        <TransitionCollection/>
                    </ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>

Answer (score 6):

As one of the comments mentioned, simply adding this did the trick for me:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerTransitions> 
    <TransitionCollection/> 
</ListView.ItemContainerTransitions>
```

No need for all the other code.

Comment: This should be accepted. Also `<ListView.ItemContainerTransitions />` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

It might be in the default ItemsPanel.

You could try something like this:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
                <TransitionCollection/>
            </VirtualizingStackPanel.ChildrenTransitions>
        </VirtualizingStackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

Why though do you want to go against the fluid part of the Fast and Fluid thing of the design language? Are you trying to implement something more bland than the templates or are you planning on adding your own transitions?

Comment: Because it doesn't fit on my app. My app is a note taking app, is just plain simple but eye candy. And with that animation it slows the application. I just wanted to click add and see it there, not see how pretty it appears.

Comment: The animations in Metro aren't about pretty. They are about subtle hints to the user as to what is going on. The animations in a list would show you that an item is indeed added and where it is added. Without them - the UI just refreshes in a new state and the user has a better chance of getting confused about what just happened. That's the theory at least - I haven't seen your app. :)

Comment: I like your approach better.

Comment: Actually, today after knowing of ItemContainerTransitions I would probably use that, I just possibly wouldn't do that in a style.

Comment: When you have a short list you want to clear all items and add new ones, animation kind of overlaps... That's a reason for me to disable animations.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Damir's answer, this is how I did it. Just add this in your **App.xaml**

```
<Application...>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            ...
            <Style TargetType="ListView">
                <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <TransitionCollection/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work --

```
listView.ItemContainerTransitions = null;
```

You have to assign a new reference (or null) to the `ItemContainerTransitions` property. Changing the values in the collection already referenced by this property will not work.

This will NOT work --

```
listView.ItemContainerTransitions.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the suggested ItemContainerTransitions removal, there's an additional animation you might want to remove.

In the ListViewItem template there's a transform animation called ContentPresenterTranslateTransform, it slides the item content into place. You can just remove that animation from template's storyboards.

Answer (score -1):

In UWP, I created the following code to remove the animation:

```
// Remove Add/Delete animations
TransitionCollection tc = _listView.ItemContainerTransitions;
for (int i = tc.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) if (tc[i] is AddDeleteThemeTransition) tc.RemoveAt(i);
```