# How can I animate listview's item removal from view model?

Tags: c#, animation, xamarin.forms

How can I create an animation of a `ListView`'s item removal? I am using view model and it should be from view model (I'm guessing here).

```
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectivosDoDia}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorColor="Transparent" x:Name="lista" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <local:ShadowFrame StartColor="{Binding CorInicio}" EndColor="{Binding CorFim}" HeightRequest="75" Padding="0" HasShadow="True">
...

                                            <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding IconeSeleccionado}"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding BindingContext.MarcarObjectivoCompleto, Source={x:Reference homePage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/> 
                                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                            </Image>

                                        </Grid>
                                    </local:ShadowFrame>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

```
        public ICommand MarcarObjectivoCompleto
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command<Objectivo>((obj) =>
                {
                    obj.Cumprido = true;
                    obj.CorInicio = Color.FromHex("#00778F");
                    obj.CorFim = Color.FromHex("#0B5799");
                    obj.IconeSeleccionado = ImageSource.FromFile("vistoP.png");
                    obj.CorTexto = Color.White;
                    ObjectivosDoDia.Remove(obj);
                });
            }
        }
```

I want to animate the item being removed from the `ListView` using fade animation. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Anyone ? Please i really need some help...

Comment: Well, xamarin doesn't provide an easy way to accomplish this, you'll either make a hack in forms, or use custom renderer, do you have an example of this animation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556605/how-to-remove-listviews-add-item-animation provides the basics of listView Animations, but Phillpotts made his list view animation work open source as you can see https://twitter.com/kphillpotts/status/1136772771218726913

Comment: thanks guys. i think after i finish my project, im gonna move on to another way to develop mobile apps instead of xamarin...